# OpenAL alcCaptureOpenDevice crashes on Blackberry Q10

Tags: blackberry-10, openal, audio-capture

Q10 firmware: 10.1.0.4285

I'm trying to use OpenAL to capture sound, but on Q10 I've got problem that cannot open capture device. Open capture device on simulator (v10_1_X.1483) is OK though (I haven't tested actual sound capturing yet).

Below is my code snippet for that.

```
qDebug() << "Available capture devices:";
devices = alcGetString(NULL, ALC_CAPTURE_DEVICE_SPECIFIER);
ptr = devices;
while (*ptr) {
    qDebug() << "** [" << ptr << "]";
    ptr += strlen(ptr) + 1;
}

// Open the capture device
qDebug() << "Opening capture device:";
const ALchar *deviceName;
ptr = devices;
while (*ptr) {
    qDebug() << "** Opening device [" << ptr << "]";
    captureDev = alcCaptureOpenDevice(ptr, 8000, AL_FORMAT_MONO8, 800);
    if (captureDev == NULL) {
        qDebug() << "** Unable to open capture device: [" << ptr << "]";
    } else {
        deviceName = ptr;
        qDebug() << "** Opened device [" << deviceName << "]";
        break;
    }
    ptr += strlen(ptr) + 1;
}
```

And below is output result:

```
Available capture devices: 
**  [ ASOUND Default ] 
**  [ MSM, MSM PCM 0 (CARD=0,DEV=1) ] 
Opening capture device: 
** Opening device [ ASOUND Default ] 
** Unable to open capture device: [ ASOUND Default ] 
** Opening device [ MSM, MSM PCM 0 (CARD=0,DEV=1) ] 
AL lib: asound_open_capture: Could not open capture device 'default': No such file or directory

Process 75899061 (BBTestSound) terminated SIGSEGV code=1 fltno=11 ip=78658774(/base/usr/lib/libOpenAL.so.1@StopThread+0x57f) mapaddr=00018774. ref=00000018
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yaiba,
you need to ask for permissions for recording audio at the bar-descriptor file.
After that, you will be able to use the ASOUND Default.

Best regards,

Rodrigo Peixoto
BlackBerry - Application Development Consultant